# When Using Cuda: TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'activation')

Tags: python, tensorflow

Just installed Cuda with Anaconda. When trying to run the same model that worked before the installation I get the error message on the first addition of the lstm layer: TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'activation').

My code looks like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Embedding, LSTM, Dropout, CuDNNLSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import seaborn as sns


model = Sequential()
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, input_shape=(800,1), activation='tanh', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(128, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not feasible to support this since the underlying cudnn API does not let us choose the activation function for LSTMS: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-developer-guide/index.html#cudnnRNNMode_t

Please check the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24375

open issue for the same is over here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8510